# When passing a function that contains window to a child iframe, the value of window references the parent window, not the child's window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Imagine I have a same domain iframe on my page:

Parent:

```html
<body>
  <iframe src="frame.html"></iframe>
  <script>
    // cannot change this function
    const func = () => {
      console.log(window.location.pathname)
    }

    document.querySelector('#frame').contentWindow.test = () => {
      func()
    }
  </script>
  </script>
</body>
```

Frame:

```html
<body>
  <script>
    window.test()
  </script>
</body>
```

This child iframe will output the pathname of the parent window, which makes sense. Is it possible to change where `window` points to so it points to the frame's `window`?

I'm hoping for it to log `/frame.html`

EDIT: I would dependency inject `window` into the function, but I have embedded libraries out of my control which expect `window` to be properly set

Answer (score 0):

`func()` is logging the fixed value `window.location.pathname` which is relative to the parent of the script in which it is defined.

Either you need to use another function, to which is passed the relevant parameter for use as its argument or which extrapolates the path of the `iframe`, or you need to cut out all the middle men and cut to the chase i.e. put the required function in a script in the `iframe`.

Simply: the `console.log` needs access to the information you want it to log, which is currently not the information it has, and all the while the information it has is hard coded to reference its own `window` it will be useless for your purposes.